# What is the difference between using TTimer and using TThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have developed an application that connects to SQL Server database and reads some data from tables every 1 second.
For this purpose I use `TTimer` but the delay of the database response affects my application performance.

I know a little about `TThread` in Delphi, what I want to know now is the difference between using `TTimer` and `TThread`? And using `TThread` instead of `TTimer` is useful for my application performance in this case?

Comment: If you really need a direct connection with the database (without a business layer), consider using DBMS events, as it sounds you are periodically checking if there's something new in a table (if your DBMS and client side supports them). If not, move that polling stuff into a thread. Long running code inside a `TTimer` tick event blocks the main thread and causes the app. to be *not responding*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two can be found in their class definition:

- `TTimer = class(TComponent)`
- `TThread = class`

While the `TTimer` class extends `TComponent` and is a *component* itself, `TThread` is an abstract class which extends `TObject`.

`TThread` exposes static methods like `TThread.Sleep` and a peculiar protected method called `Execute` which must be implemented in the derived class in order to perform the desired job.
`TThread` directly uses the [Processes and Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx) functions of the guest OS.

---

> ... for this purpose I use `TTimer` but the delay of Database response affect on my application performance

The reason why this happens is because the `OnTimer` event of the `TTimer` object is executed in the calling thread: when a `TTimer` component is put into a form and its `OnTimer` event is implemented, the code is executed in the main thread.

The `TThread` approach is more flexible: if for some reason the code must be performed in the main thread, this can be achieved nesting a [sinchronized block](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) inside the thread's `Execute` method.

---

If you want to execute database requests in a repeated manner after some time interval, you better consider using a `TThread` in combination with a `TEvent` object.

An example of class definition using `TEvent`:

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FInterval: Integer;
    FWaitEvent: TEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(Interval: Cardinal; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

The implemented class:

```
constructor TMyThread.Create(Interval: Cardinal; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FInterval := Interval;
  FWaitEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  FWaitEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  FWaitEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do begin
    //do your stuff

    //wait fo some amount of time before continue the execution
    if wrSignaled = FWaitEvent.WaitFor(FInterval) then
      Break;
  end;
end;
```

The `WaitFor` method called on the `FWaitEvent` object allows to wait for the desired amount of time.

The implementation of the thread's `TerminatedSet` method allows to put the `FWaitEvent` object in a *signaled* state and then exit from the thread before the interval has elapsed.

Comment: You should ***never*** have `inherited` inside `Execute` - this will lead to an abstract error.

Comment: @JerryDodge oops... it's `abstract` and not only `virtual`!!! I littered my `Execute` methods with the `inherited` keyword for years... thank you for enlightening my path!  I'm going to edit this and some other post of mine here on SO =:-)

Comment: @JerryDodge my last comment needs to be a little bit revised because I forgot the reason why I always used `inherited` and it never raised an *abstract error*. Even though you're right saying that `inherited` shouldn't be used with abstract methods from an OOP perspective, the Delphi compiler has the capability of eliminating the call when the keyword is used *without parameters* to refer to an inherited abstract method.

Comment: Thank you Fantaghirocco for your complete discussion about TTread Class and difference between TTread and TTimer and thank you for your useful Example

Comment: @Fayyaz I'm happy to have been helpful. If I'm allowed, I consider my answer as an extension of [that of Remy Lebeau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580862/what-is-the-difference-between-using-ttimer-and-using-tthread/32580971#32580971) who synthetically expresses the same concepts. I didn't focus on `TTimer` because of his good explaination about it

Answer (score 5):

TTimer is a message-based timer.  It posts WM_TIMER messages to the message queue of the thread that creates it.  Your database operations are blocking that thread from processing new messages in a timely manner. Assuming your TTimer is in the main UI thread, that is why your app performance suffers.  Moving the database operations into a worker thread prevents the main thread's message loop from being blocked.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that having a database query execute once per second regardless of any other criteria is generally not a good idea.

Comment: thank you Remy Lebeau for your help and Thank you Andy_D I will Consider your comment

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't specifically address your q, but as noted in a comment to one of
the other answers, polling a database at the frequency you're doing isn't a good idea, especially if other users are trying to access it.

There are various ways to get notifications from database servers when data changes, without needing to continually poll them.  This Embarcadero paper has a very useful review of what's available for various DBMSs:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29

If your Delphi version includes FireDAC, as you'll see from the link that you could use TFDEventAlerter to receive notifications of data changes on the server if your DBMS supports
it.

If you're using Interbase or Firebird (and maybe some others), there are alternate Delphi components available that don't require FireDAC, e.g. TIBEventAlerter in the IBExpress ibrary for Interbase.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance about DBMS

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keeping your TTimer if you want to on your main form

Then inside your TTimer create a TTask

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Tutorial:_Using_Tasks_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library

https://delphiaball.co.uk/2014/09/08/using-ttask-from-the-parallel-programming-library/

And doing all your DB work in there, but as others have suggested checking every 1 second is not very good practice.

Something like this :

`Global var downloaddata : ITask`

```
TimerTimer.Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if downloaddata.Status = TTaskStatus.Running then
    begin
    //If it is already running don't start it again
        Exit;
    end;

    downloaddata := TTask.Create (procedure ()
    var //Create Thread var here
        MyConnection : TFDConnection;
        MyQuery : TFDQuery;
    begin
        //Do all your Query logic in here

        //If you need to do any UI related modifications
         TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,procedure()
            begin 
                //Remeber to wrap them inside a Syncronize
            end);
     //If you have Query variables and this is running on mobile with ARC 
     //remember to set their connection :  properties to nil to avoid memory leaks
     //http:stackoverflow.com/questions/32010583/what-happens-to-database-connection-objectsmydac-tmyconnection-under-arc
    MyQuery.connection := nil
end);
downloaddata.start
```

There are much better solutions available this is just a quick basic answer but it should guide you into something better.

Doing logic in your thread would keep your UI repsonsive, but beware that TThread.Syncronize will wait for the main form and depending on the situation TThread.queue would be a better call.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Whether TTimer or TThread is used, it is recommended to run a query only to get data that has been changed. To do that you need to:

- Add a 'modified' (TIMESTAMP) column to each table
- Add a 'deleted'  (TIMESTAMP) column to each table
- Add a trigger for INSERT OR UPDATE to update 'modified' field with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- Add a DESC index on the 'modified' field to speed up queries
- Never delete a row, only update 'deleted' field with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

After first read, it is enough to ask for new data:

```
select c.* from 'customers' as c where c.modified > '2019...'
```

You read all data at once and store the result in a temporary memory-array.
After closed the dataset >> you compare (syncronized) with the main-array.

To update data >> run a separate SQL.